# errors in crontab file, can't install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

Me new in ruby on rails. I make `schedule.rb` by using the *whenever* gem, and write a code

```
set :environment, "development"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}

every '* * * * * *' do    
  command "echo 'you can use raw cron syntax too'"
end
```

I already did `whenever`, but when I update crontab it gives following error

```
"-":3: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
[fail] Couldn't write crontab; try running `whenever' with no options to
       ensure your schedule file is valid.
```

What is its solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unix crontab has **5 fields**; minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week.

This line:

```
every '* * * * * *' do
       1 2 3 4 5 6 <- Error
```

You entered too many fields.

Comment: One more think if u know how can I see the output.....I did whenever --update-crontab and file updated....but output not shows

Comment: You mean how to look at the current crontab? Type `crontab -l`.